# Configuring NGINX for a cakephp web project 404 not found

Tags: php, cakephp, nginx

I have a problem here, 
I installed nginx on a Ubuntu VM and pulled my cakephp project into /var/www. But the problem is that when I try to access to the index.php file into the webroot folder with nginx I have a 404 Not Found error. The routing works though because it writes in the URL "/members/login".

Do you have any suggestion ?

Here is my default conf nginx file :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/projet_web_cakephp/webroot;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name mu-project.hd.free.fr;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I configure nginx rewrite rules to get CakePHP working on CentOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046439/how-do-i-configure-nginx-rewrite-rules-to-get-cakephp-working-on-centos)

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts